# How can I save a Word document back to the main server from an ASP.NET intranet?

Tags: asp.net, ms-word

I have a ASP.NET intranet application that has a document library section. The user can click on a link to a MS-Word document that resides on the server and can then edit the document if required within the browser (IE).

The problem is that when they come to save their changes it needs to write it back to the server but instead wants to save it on their local system.

Any ideas how I can get it to save back to the main server ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link to the word document can be a file:// url.

Using this method the user can open the file directly on the share.

Answer (score 4):

you need to upload the file back to the server.

Is this a internet or intranet application? if intranet you could save directly to \\myServer\myFolder\...

If it's a internet application, so the end user does not access to the server files directly you need to create a Office Add In (using [Visual Studio Tools for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d(VS.80).aspx)), called "Save to Server" and that will run "http://www.mydomain.com/updatefile.aspx" and that page will do a Update.

remember, Update with a filename diferent from the original, and if the update was ok, then delete the old, and rename the new (or give the user a version system and rename the file on the server to [myFile]_[currentDate].docx for example.

links:

[How to upload a file to a Web server in ASP.NET by using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323246)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your intranet applicaiton supports writing back to the server, you would need to give the account that the web application runs as permission to write to the folder the documents are stored in, unless it is using impersonation then the users it is impersonating would need ther permissions.